# css style for input box displaying in iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, key, return

I have created a style for an input text box, I want the text to start from the top left corner. When entering texts in iPhone, I want the "Return" key available on the keyboard, so people can separate texts in paragraphs, here is my script:

```
<style>
.inputs>input[type=text],.inputs>input[type=password],.inputs>input[type=number]{
height: 100px!important;
vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
```

It is currently vertically aligned in the middle, instead of the top. And all I have is an "OK" button to submit my text answers when entering texts in iPhone, instead of the "Return" key.

I believe I need additional styles to control the "OK" to "Return" to display, but just can't find anywhere on the internet to show me how.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: actually i checked the example and i said so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multi-line text input, you need a [`<TEXTAREA>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) not and `<INPUT>`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I can only use CSS to alter the look and feel of the text box, instead of altering the structure completely, here is the structure: <div id="Q10_inputs" class="inputs inputwrapper open"> <input id="Q10" name="Q10" value="" type="text" /></div> so I hope it will help with issue. I have check it in IE, Firefox or Safari in a desktop device, and it's looking perfectly fine, except in iPhone

Comment: @user1041029 I am 100% certain that the text does not vertically align to the top in Chrome and Firefox on the desktop, because it is impossible in an `<input type="text" />`. And you ***absolutely cannot*** have multiple lines in an `<input type="text"/>`. You HAVE to use a `<textarea/>`

Comment: Thanks Strelok, my choice is very limited, so I will see how can I implement <textarea/> into this.